# Add onclick event to the radio button that added dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm creating an online exam page with 30 radiobuttons that are created dynamically at runtime.

How will I get the `click` event of each radiobutton and tag it in my method that I will check if the next question is need to be jump or escape.

Example:

If I'm in question 10 and answer = "Yes", redirect me to Question 15, else go to the next question

Answer (score 0):

Use the following statement:

```
AddHandler radioButton.Click, AddressOf instance.MethodName
```

---

Refer to [How to: Dynamically Bind Event Handlers at Run Time in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3d01ft1.aspx)

Comment: the code is work good but AddressOf doest allow method that passes parameter.

Comment: @akram - what will i do if i want to pass the radiobutton.ID and radiobutton.text

Comment: @spy: There is no need. Read [How to: Determine Which Web Server Control Raised an Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk6b17bs.aspx)

Comment: @Akram - please explained me on how to achive this. I have a dynamically radiobutton , then i will add this code in everycreation of radionbutton AddHandler NewRbt.CheckedChanged, AddressOf GetRadioButtonID, which will get the value of newly selected radio button.. i will paste my code here

Comment: For Each row As DataRow In rdt.Rows
spacer = New LiteralControl("<br />")
pnlQuestion.Controls.Add(spacer)
Dim NewRbt As RadioButton = New RadioButton()
NewRbt.ID = strQuestionId + "_" + row.Item("Answer").ToString
NewRbt.Text = row.Item("Description").ToString
NewRbt.GroupName = intQuestionNo.ToString
NewRbt.AutoPostBack = True
AddHandler NewRbt.CheckedChanged, AddressOf ValidateClick
pnlQuestion.Controls.Add(NewRbt)
Private Function ValidateClick(ByVal  As String) As String
ViewState("ControlId") =  ControlId
End Function

Comment: Im getting and errro in addessof - AddressOf' operand must be the same of a method (without Parenthesis)

Comment: @spy: the code is not readable this way. Post it in the body of your question please ..

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using an anonymous sub (VB2010 only) to write the event handler inline

```
AddHandler radioButton.Click,
    Sub(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Awesome!")            
    End Sub
```

Adapted from [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/04/16/tip-anonymous-event-handlers-in-vbnet)

You can also [use closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084937/wiring-controls-in-visual-basic-controlling-the-controls/9085580#9085580)...

Answer (score 0):

HTML code-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="RadioButtonsPanel" runat="server" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

VB Code-

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    '   Add each radio button 
    AddNewRaduiButton("MyRadio1")
    AddNewRaduiButton("MyRadio2")
    AddNewRaduiButton("MyRadio3")
    AddNewRaduiButton("MyRadio4")
End Sub

Private Sub AddNewRaduiButton(ByVal name As String)

    '   Create a new radio button 
    Dim MyRadioButton As New RadioButton

    With MyRadioButton
        .ID = name
        .AutoPostBack = True
        .Text = String.Format("Radio Button - '{0}'", name)
    End With

    '   Add the click event to go to the sub "MyRadioButton_CheckedChanged"
    AddHandler MyRadioButton.CheckedChanged, AddressOf MyRadioButton_CheckedChanged

    Page.FindControl("RadioButtonsPanel").Controls.Add(MyRadioButton)
End Sub


Protected Sub MyRadioButton_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    '   Convert the Sender object into a radio button 
    Dim ClickedRadioButton As RadioButton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)

    '   Display the radio button name
    MsgBox(String.Format("Radio Button {0} has been Updated!", ClickedRadioButton.ID))

End Sub
```