# Wiring Controls in Visual Basic, Controlling the Controls

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, stopwatch, dynamically-generated

I'm in the middle of using Visual Basic (Visual Studio 2010) to create dynamically created controls. Essentially what I'm doing is creating a label, a textbox, a label (which will act as a stopwatch), and a button (to control said stopwatch).

Each set of controls will be arranged (and named) like this in a row:

```
[LABEL]  [TEXTBOX]         [TIMER]       [BUTTON]
Labelx   ParticipantNamex  RingTimerx    ControlButtonx
```

So for a given row, I will be look like this:

```
[LABEL]  [TEXTBOX]         [TIMER]       [BUTTON]
Label1   ParticipantName1  RingTimer1    ControlButton1
```

I've gotten the bit about creating the elements dynamically as well as creating them within in a panel with a particular number attached to the end of its name on the form that I've created. What I would like to do is wire an event for the button that was dynamically created to control the stopwatch timer that was created through the same event.

So in short, I'm asking *how do you wire an event to control a particularly dynamic button?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an anonymous sub (VB2010 only) to write the event handler inline

```
Timer myTimer = New Timer
Button button = New Button
AddHandler button.Click,
    Sub(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
         ' can manipulate the Timer here 
         ' because it is captured in a closure     
         myTimer.Stop    
    End Sub
```

Adapted from [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/04/16/tip-anonymous-event-handlers-in-vbnet).

PS read [more about closures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/05/02/closures-in-vb-part-1.aspx) from our very own Jared.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I have a question then, with this code, do I have to give each object dynamically created a name?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The default Name is an empty string. As far as I know, you only have to name the control if you intend to use the Name later, maybe to [distinguish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx) different controls by their Name. (IMHO there's usually a better way). [See docs for more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx)

Comment: I discovered a small problem with this... Say I dynamically created two sets of buttons and labels, using this method only label is updated and both buttons control the same timer. (Hence why I didn't get an upvote yet.) Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you [capturing a variable defined outside a loop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/07/26/closures-in-vb-part-5-looping.aspx)? The solution is in the link. Declare a variable inside the loop instead.

Comment: No I'm referring to a label created inside the loop. My problem is that I can't seem to make a reference to the just recently created control and I can't refer to a dynamically created property