# Visual Basic - Modify Textboxes and Objects Generated in Code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, event-handling

I've written a for loop to generate several new text boxes and numericUpDowns when the application is run.

The text boxes / numericUpDowns are generated with a 2-dimensional array.

My question is: How do I handle when the text boxes / numericUpDowns are modified?

If you would like the code, just request it and I'll add it here.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wiring Controls in Visual Basic, Controlling the Controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084937/wiring-controls-in-visual-basic-controlling-the-controls)

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084937/wiring-controls-in-visual-basic-controlling-the-controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something I wrote for something similar.  It makes a grid of buttons and demonstrates how to handle the events.

```
Dim IsCreated(99) As Boolean
Dim Buttons As New Dictionary(Of String, Button)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        For i As Integer = 0 To 99
            Dim B As New Button
            Me.Controls.Add(B)
            B.Height = 30
            B.Width = 40
            B.Left = (i Mod 10) * 41
            B.Top = (i \ 10) * 31
            B.Text = Chr((i \ 10) + Asc("A")) & i Mod 10 + 1
            Buttons.Add(B.Text, B)
            B.Tag = i
            AddHandler B.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
        Next


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim B As Button = sender
        IsCreated(B.Tag) = True
        B.BackColor = Color.Red
    End Sub
```